# Hide scroll of body page when modal window is open

Tags: html, css, overflow

Is it possible to remove scroll of body page when a modal window is opened from css?
For example my body page has a height:200% so if I want to go on the bottom of page I must use scroll (overflow-y:auto). Now if I will open a modal window the scroll of body page remain active and I want it be disabled when a modal window is opened.

Thank you.

Comment: If you use `position:fixed` for the modal window it will remain in place on the screen even if the user scrolls up or down.

Comment: Yes , I know I already have position:fixed on modal but I want to disable scroll of body page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are opening a modal window when a link is click you can do the following:

```
// modal screen activate
$('a').live('click', function(){
modalScreen.show();
$('body').css('overflow','hidden');
});

// modal screen de-activate
$('body, html').live('click', function(){
modalScreen.hide();
$('body').css('overflow','auto');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are opening your lightwindow using javascript:

You could than just set the height of the body to 100% and set overflow-y to hidden. That will remove the scrollbar.

You will have to reset everything on close of the lightwindow.

Comment: I use wicket, and yes in back of modal window is a mega javascript, I prefer to not modify that. For that reason I try to find a way to disable overflow for body page with css or jQuery.

Comment: You can set any css you want using jQuery: $('body').css({'height': '100%', 'overflow-y': 'hidden'}); Something like that should do the trick (untested).

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` and set your `left` and `top` to percentages, then `margin-left` to a negative value of the width in pixels.  e.g. `width: 700px; left: 50%, margin-left: -350px;` in order to center horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Or just add and remove classes to your script:

```
$('body').addClass('modal-open'); //when modal is open
$('body').removeClass('modal-open'); //when modal is closed
```

Then you can go to your css file and add multiple css styles. For hiding the scroll bar use:

```
.modal-open {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Especially when you want to change more things I prefer this way, but that's my opinion. Use whatever you like!